# Копирование файлов посредством ansible Windows

Tags: windows, ansible

Знающие подскажите. Необходимо скопировать файл с удаленного сервера на удаленный пк

```
- name: Copy file     
  hosts: all     
  tasks:  
      win_copy:  
      remote_src: \\fileserver\file  
      dest: C:\folder
```

Что не так?

Comment: А `dest` - это всё-таки локальный или тоже удалённый?

Comment: Удаленный. По сути фигурируют 3 группы: 1. Сервер Ansible 2. Удаленный файловый сервер 3. Группа удаленных ПК

Comment: Копируем файл или всё-таки папку с файлами?

Comment: Возможны варианты, в данной ситуации только файл

Answer (score 2):

Папка:

```
- name: Sync some directory
  hosts: all
  strategy: free
  serial:
    - "100%"
  tasks:

  - name: Copy to C:\folder
    when: ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
    block:
      - win_file:
          path: 'C:\folder'
          state: directory
      - win_robocopy:
          src: \\fileserver\folder\
          dest: 'C:\folder\'
```

Файл:

```
- name: Copy 1c hasp config file
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
  win_copy:
    src: \\myserver.mydomain\1с\ini\nethasp.ini
    dest: '%ProgramFiles(x86)%\1cv8\conf\nethasp.ini'
    remote_src: yes
    force: yes
  tags:
    - windows
    - 1c
    - config
    - hasp
```